# What's the meaning of "has not" in a questiontional statement?

Tags: question-marks

> Sirius’s letter was almost as short as the previous one.
>
> *Be at stile at end of road out of Hogsmeade (past Dervish and Banges) at two o’clock on Saturday afternoon. Bring as much food as you can.*
>
> “**He hasn’t come back to Hogsmeade**?” said Ron incredulously.
>
> “It looks like it, doesn’t it?” said Hermione.
>
> “I can’t believe him,” said Harry tensely, “if he’s caught . . .”
>
> “Made it so far, though, hasn’t he?” said Ron. “And it’s not like the
> place is swarming with dementors anymore.”

In this context above which comes from *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*, what does Ron mean? I know "He hasn’t come back to Hogsmeade"'s meaning but after adding a question mark, did the meaning change to the opposite?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making a statement with the tone of a question is symbolized by ending it with a question mark, and it expresses the speaker's surprise or even disbelief at what he has just said. Likely, what he said is a repetition of something that was said to him, or an implication of something that was said to him (as in this case, apparently).

A clue to this meaning is the word *incredulously* -

[AHD *incredulous*](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=incredulous)

1. Skeptical; disbelieving: incredulous of stories about flying saucers.
2. Expressive of disbelief: an incredulous stare.